# Fade <div> element after submit button has been pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have simple google maps div element. When user clicks `Submit` button expensive calculations gets trigged on backend therefore I want fade the whole google map in order to prevent user from navigating over and illustrate that job is in progress.

Simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/8jhsxbpo/4/

```
  <div id="map_canvas" ></div>
  <button ng-click="getPlace()" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Note: Submit is not blocking the rest of the page. Doing it using angular `$http` service.

```
$scope.getPlace = function(term, locale) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/search', {
        params: {
            term: term,
            locale: locale
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        renderMap(response);
    });
};
```

My project is written on Bootstrap 3 + Angular Js.

Question: How do I fade or disable element and display loading icon while job is in progress?

Comment: That usually done with either div covering the entire window and a loading message or gif, as for button you can always set its property to disabled.

Comment: @KarthikMR, Thanks for response. Submit is not blocking the rest of the page. Doing it using angular $http service.

Comment: are u submitting through ajax call? if so pls post the code.

Comment: @KarthikMR, I am using angular `$http` not sure what technology is underneath of that, but assume it very similar to ajax, since it not blocking a page. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: post your submit code

Comment: @KarthikMR, thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before making the request fadeout the map, display loading text, and after getting the response, hide loading text and  fadein the map

```
$scope.getPlace = function(term, locale) {
    $("#map_canvas").fadeOut();
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "table";
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/search', {
        params: {
           term: term,
           locale: locale
        }
   }).then(function(response){
       $("#loading").hide();
       $("#map_canvas").fadeIn();
       renderMap(response);
   });
};
```

Add div and span element and set style.

```
 <div id="loading" class="loading-div">
     <span class="loading-span">Loading...</span>
 </div>
 <div id="map_canvas" ></div>

<style>
  .loading-div {
  display : none;
  width: 250px; //set width of map div
  height: 400px; //set height of map div
  text-align: center;
}

.loading-span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I add loading div so that it would be in a middle of my `map` element and not overloaded?

Comment: set the height and width of the loading div which is of the values of map.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" ></div>
<button ng-click="getPlace()" type="button">Submit</button> 

var showLoader = function () {

    $("#map_canvas").hide();
    var loader = '<img id="loaderImage" src="/Content/Images/Loaders/loading4.gif" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />';

    $("#loading").addClass("text-center");
    $("#loading").append(loader);
};

var hideLoader = function () {

    $("#map_canvas").show();
    $("#loading" + " img:last-child").remove();
    $("#loading").removeClass("text-center");

};
```